# Emacs 24.4 on Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

I am trying to get Emacs 24.4 running on Mac (Maverick).

I have tried following [these instructions](http://www.wickeddutch.com/2013/12/30/building-emacs-for-mac-os-x), but when I run:

```
./build-emacs gzr
```

I get the error:

```
bzr: ERROR: exceptions.ImportError: Unable to load subvertpy extensions:  dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/subvertpy/client.so, 2): Library not loaded:   /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/subvertpy/client.so
  Reason: image not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 930, in exception_to_return_code
return the_callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 1121, in run_bzr
ret = run(*run_argv)
   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 673, in run_argv_aliases
return self.run(**all_cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 697, in run
return self._operation.run_simple(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/cleanup.py", line 136, in run_simple
self.cleanups, self.func, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/cleanup.py", line 166, in _do_with_cleanups
 result = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/builtins.py", line 2214, in run
show_bzrdir_info(newdir, verbose=0, outfile=self.outf)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/info.py", line 378, in show_bzrdir_info
outfile)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/info.py", line 394, in show_component_info
format = describe_format(control, repository, branch, working)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/info.py", line 499, in describe_format
format = controldir.format_registry.make_bzrdir(key)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/controldir.py", line 1348, in make_bzrdir
return self.get(key)()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/registry.py", line 177, in get
return self._dict[self._get_key_or_default(key)].get_obj()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/registry.py", line 74, in get_obj
self._obj = get_named_object(self._module_name, self._member_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/pyutils.py", line 51, in get_named_object
obj = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, from_list)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins/svn/workingtree.py", line 28, in <module>
import subvertpy
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/subvertpy/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
raise ImportError("Unable to load subvertpy extensions: %s" % e)
ImportError: Unable to load subvertpy extensions: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site- packages/subvertpy/client.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/subvertpy/client.so
Reason: image not found

bzr 2.6.0 on python 2.6.8 (Darwin-13.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit)
arguments: ['/usr/local/bin/bzr', 'init-repo', 'emacs-bzr']
plugins: bash_completion[2.6.0], bzrtools[2.5.0], changelog_merge[2.6.0],
colo[0.4.0], email[unknown], explorer[1.3.0], fastimport[0.14.0dev],
git[0.6.11], grep[2.6.0], keychain[0.1.0], launchpad[2.6.0], loom[2.2.0],
netrc_credential_store[2.6.0], news_merge[2.6.0], pipeline[1.4.0],
po_merge[2.6.0], qbzr[0.23.1], rewrite[0.6.3], svn[1.2.2], upload[1.1.0],
weave_fmt[2.6.0], xmloutput[0.8.8]
encoding: 'utf-8', fsenc: 'utf-8', lang: 'en_US'

*** Bazaar has encountered an internal error.  This probably indicates a
bug in Bazaar.  You can help us fix it by filing a bug report at
    https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+filebug
including this traceback and a description of the problem.
```

Any ideas? Another way?

Answer (score 34):

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh) provides Emacs 24.4 as well, with

```
$ brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) on OS X 10.9.5 currently, this version is the one from [Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and used with It's All Text! for Firefox to write this answer.  ;)

Obviously most people generally opt for homebrew (as the top answer indicates), but since homebrew has a tendency to screw with /usr/local to such an extent that it won't cope with alternative (e.g. custom compiled or original) installations of Python, I can't/won't run it (so I compile from source or use MacPorts).  For those in a similar position to me regarding homebrew (and I know it's not everyone), then give the Emacs for Mac OS X version a shot, failing that try MacPorts and if it's still not ideal [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/138835/which-version-of-emacs-makes-the-best-use-of-the-mac-gui) has many good responses, depending on your circumstances, particularly [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/138838/256374).

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with various emacs installs on OSX, so eventually I switched to MacPorts. It has emacs 24.3 available.

Answer (score 0):

The current "bzr" release doesn't work out of the box on Mavericks. You can either install another prebuilt variant (from MacPorts, homebrew, or fink), or try to manually upgrade the library [subvertpy](https://github.com/jelmer/subvertpy).

I use MacPorts when I use `bzr` and when I run `autogen.sh`. However, it must be disabled when you run `./configure --with-ns` and `make install`. (I use two separate terminal windows with different PATH environment variables for this.)